Weird solution for functional equation
The functional equation i am dealing with is as follows
$$f: R \rightarrow R, f(x^2 + x + 3) + 2f(x^2 - 3x + 5) = 6x^2 - 10x + 17, \forall x \in R$$
I am to find the function $f(x)$
I tried various values of $x$ and thought maybe something would simply however the only insights i could come with was the values of the function at $x=5$ and $x = 3$
$$f(5) = 7 \text{ and }f(3) = 3$$
I looked at the solution for the question in my textbook and it was as follows

I did not understand a single bit of this solution, firstly how is $f$ a linear polynomial?,next what is the triple line symbol in the place of $=$.
The solution did not make sense to me.
Could someone please explain the solution to me, any help would be highly appreciated!

I don't think it's at all obvious that $f$ must be a linear polynomial.

Solution here using the change of variable $X=1-x$ (found using formula searching tool approach0)

Note that $x^2 + x + 3$ and $x^2 - 3 x + 5$ both have minimum value $11/4$, so $f$ can be anything at all on the interval $(-\infty, 11/4)$.
